# how much of data in pure html would there be for small european country

Tags: web-crawler

Ok, maybe this question is bizarre, but I'm planing to write a crawler for pages in Lithuanian only and I'm trying to estimate how much of data that would be (and therefore how long would that take). Perhaps someone else has similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough estimate can be made by looking at some statistics:

- The [average page size](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/web-metrics) is 320KB
- The population of Lithuania is 0.04% of the world population
- There are about a [trillion pages on the internet](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/we-knew-web-was-big.html)
- The [compression ratio of markup files](https://superuser.com/questions/139253/what-is-the-maximum-compression-ratio-of-gzip) is between 2:1 and 4:1 ([also confirmed by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/web-metrics)).

So if you give each country in the world a proportionate ownership of the pages on the internet (it's not a correct assumption, but it should be a helpful one), then 0.04% of 1 trillion pages is 400 million pages in Lithuania.

400 million * 320KB = 119.20929 terabytes

If you compress the pages and you assume a **best case scenario** of 4:1 compression, then you're looking at about 30 terabytes. I'd still say that you need a 120 terabytes to be safe. If you assume the current prices of about $100 per TB, you'll need between $3,000 and $12,000 just in hard drives to store this data.

Now, the **big** question is: do you actually need all of that data?

Comment: Thanks for the estimate and links. If it's really something like that I'll settle down with some smaller subset:)